# Salesforce MIAW: User message not sent from Community

Tags: messaging, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vup4h.jpg)I have setup MIAW in my org and while testing from Experience builder for a contact, it says message not sent. However when i use Test Messaging from Embedded service it works fine.

Log to experience as user then click MIAW embeded messaging component. Fill the pre-chat form and start conversation.
I do receive request as Agent and accept it
When community users try to send any message it says Resend- Not sent. Resent is also not helping.

Can someone suggest any solution.

Comment: Is this about programming? If so, please [edit] and add the relevant code as a [mcve]. If not, it's off-topic here (see [help/on-topic]) but may fit on [salesforce.se]. Make sure to check their help section for on-topic and required details.